# In C, whether the behavior of adding a number i to a pointer adds i*sizeof(datatype) is compiler dependent?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the following pseudo code, when a number i is added to the pointer abc, the next array index is pointed.
My application is expected to work as compiler independent and also similar snippet may be used for different data types. So is this a compiler dependent behavior ?

```
disp( void* abc)
{
   int i = 0;
   int n = 8;

   for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
   {
      printf("\n %d",*((int*)abc+i) );
   }
}

int main()
{
   int abc[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

   disp(abc);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `disp( void* abc)` is not standard C, so it is non-portable and will not compile on a standard compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you are safe. It is given by the standard:

*6.5.6 Additive operators:*

> "8. When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
>   [...]"

This basically means, that a pointer to a `Type` is interpreted as an array of `Type`, and additions and subtractions can be viewed as operations on the index of such an array.

Since you cast the `void*` to something meaningful it's ok, because the pointer gets reinterpreted.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's defined by the C standard. It will work the same on all compilers that implement C.

It's the basis for all pointer arithmetic in C, which is very commonly used.

Comment: ,He want to use the same code snippet for different data types,so if he pass char array address instead of int will the code work?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code is well-formed (you're missing a return type but it's okay for a *pseudocode*)

```
void disp( void* abc )
```

the answer is: you're using [pointers arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_arrays) which is a standard-compliant behavior implemented by (I believe) every C compiler, thus your code is not compiler dependent. There are some differences (mostly regarding issues where the standard doesn't dictate something specific or leaves it as *implementation dependent* or *no diagnostic required*) where compilers might differ, but if you follow the C standard you should be good to go.

A word of advice on **platform dependent** issues: if you did something like

```
// Assuming char = 1 byte, int = 4 bytes
printf("\n %d", *((char*)abc+4*i) );
```

that would assume an integer == 4 bytes. And that is **not** platform independent (you can't assume an integer is always 4 bytes on every machine on the planet).

Comment: The char type isn't platform-independent either, so even if you fixed the code to `*((char*)abc+sizeof(int)*i)` it would still be non-portable. Never use the char type for anything else but strings.