# HeapFree Has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, free

I've been messing around with malloc and free and I've been having a problem where when I call free visual studio says my program has triggered a breakpoint. This is the error I receive:

HEAP: Free Heap block 5371d0 modified at 537230 after it was freed

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <malloc.h>


struct STestStruct
{
    STestStruct(int _a, int _b, int _c)
    : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c)
    {
    }

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    void* myMem = malloc(sizeof(STestStruct) * 2);
    STestStruct* testStruct = (STestStruct*)myMem;
    (*testStruct) = STestStruct(1, 2, 3);

    // If I comment this and the next line out, everything is fine
    STestStruct* testStruct2 = testStruct + sizeof(STestStruct); 
    (*testStruct2) = STestStruct(1, 2, 3);


    free(myMem);

    return 0;
}
```

What confuses me is that I'm not modifying anything in the pointer after I call free. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Look again at what the + operator does for pointers.

Comment: Kind of related. I think it works exactly the same in c++ and you can find a similar passage in standard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116884/in-c-whether-the-behavior-of-adding-a-number-i-to-a-pointer-adds-isizeofdatat/24116969#24116969

Comment: Note: it causes undefined behaviour to use `malloc` with a non-POD class. (You can use type-trait `std::is_pod<STestStruct>::value` to check its POD-ness. Use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are not (necessarily) incremented by `n` bytes when you add `n` to them.  They are incremented by `sizeof(*p) * n` bytes.

So, you're incrementing `testStruct2` by `sizeof(STestStruct) * sizeof(STestStruct)` bytes, far too many.  Only needed to add `1`, i.e., "move to the block for the next `STestStruct` object.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I was making such a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
STestStruct* testStruct2 = testStruct + 1;
```

as pointers are always incremented in units of the size of their base type.